# c++ can't find detected memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm fairly new to c++ and i'm having some difficulties. 
I'm trying to build a String class that wrapps around c-strings

Now after some time i realized that there are some memory leaks in the heap, but i can't seem to find the mistake.

This is my Header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class String final {
    size_t m_len;
    size_t m_start;
    shared_ptr<char> m_string;

public:
    String();                   // Standard Constr
    String(const String& s);    // Copy Constr
    String(const char* s);      // Typconvert Constr

                                // Deconstr
    ~String();
}
```

These are the constructors in the .cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyString.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

String::String() : m_len(0), m_start(0), m_string(nullptr)
{  
}

String::String(const String &obj) : m_len(obj.m_len), m_start(obj.m_start), m_string(obj.m_string)
{
}

String::String(const char* obj) : m_len(strlen(obj))
{
    shared_ptr<char> ptr(unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[m_len]));
    m_string = ptr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= m_len; i++) {
        *(m_string.get() + i*sizeof(char)) = obj[i];
        if (i == m_len)
        {
            *(m_string.get() + i*sizeof(char)) = '\0';
        }
    }
}

String::~String() 
{
    m_string.reset();
}
```

And this is my main:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyString.h"
#include <iostream>

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    String s0;
    String s1("");
    String s2("abc");
    String s3("ab");

    String s00(s0);
    String s11(s1);
    String s22(s2);

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Now when i run this i get an error:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{66} normal block at 0x00668458, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <X             f > 58 AB 0E 01 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 D8 8D 66 00 
{65} normal block at 0x00668DD8, 2 bytes long.
 Data: <ab> 61 62 
{64} normal block at 0x00668D98, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <X             f > 58 AB 0E 01 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 F8 91 66 00 
{63} normal block at 0x006691F8, 3 bytes long.
 Data: <abc> 61 62 63 
{62} normal block at 0x00668C60, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <X             f > 58 AB 0E 01 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 D8 8F 66 00 
{61} normal block at 0x00668FD8, 0 bytes long.
 Data: <> öß³‘@þÿÿÿ÷O
Object dump complete.
Debug Error!

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#65) at 0x00668DD8.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

I can't figure out where that is coming from. I thought about the deconstructor and tried to take it out, so that it would write one for me, but that didn't work either. Also, the code block that seems to break the program is this one:

```
void* __CRTDECL operator new(size_t const size)
{
    for (;;)
    {
    if (void* const block = malloc(size))
    {
        return block;
    }

    if (_callnewh(size) == 0)
    {
        if (size == SIZE_MAX)
        {
            __scrt_throw_std_bad_array_new_length();
        }
        else
        {
            __scrt_throw_std_bad_alloc();
        }
    }

    // The new handler was successful; try to allocate again...
}
}
```

from new_scalar.cpp.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Did you know that we have `std::string` which manages all of this for you?

Comment: You are missing some of the members for the full rule of three (read of on it and rule of five, rule of zero etc.). You also are not dumping in the correct scope. The memory is only reclaimed after the debug dump happens. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38437543/3747990. Add additional braces before s0 and after s22.

Comment: Never seen so complex code for a so simple job! What the hell is defining a pointer in the class and again one in the method and assign one to the other... using strlen but not strcpy? Why? Reinventing the wheel seems to be nice job. shared pointer around unique pointer... Who is owner of the string memory? The object?

Comment: `shared_ptr<char> ptr(unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[m_len]));` - whut

Comment: Thanks for your replies. It is a guided exercise that should get us going on pointers and such. I added the extra scope around the calls, but it didnt seem to change anything. as i said i'm new to c++, just trying to pick up as much as possible.

Comment: @M.M Probably to steal the array deleter from `unique_ptr<char[]>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using valgrind you see your problems:

```
==20490== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20490== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20490== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20490== Command: go
==20490== 
==20490== Invalid write of size 1
==20490==    at 0x8048C76: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:38)
==20490==    by 0x80487E6: main (main.cpp:59)
==20490==  Address 0x443fa58 is 0 bytes after a block of size 0 alloc'd
==20490==    at 0x402AF41: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==20490==    by 0x8048BDC: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:34)
==20490==    by 0x80487E6: main (main.cpp:59)
==20490== 
==20490== Invalid write of size 1
==20490==    at 0x8048C82: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:41)
==20490==    by 0x80487E6: main (main.cpp:59)
==20490==  Address 0x443fa58 is 0 bytes after a block of size 0 alloc'd
==20490==    at 0x402AF41: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==20490==    by 0x8048BDC: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:34)
==20490==    by 0x80487E6: main (main.cpp:59)
==20490== 
==20490== Invalid write of size 1
==20490==    at 0x8048C76: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:38)
==20490==    by 0x80487F6: main (main.cpp:60)
==20490==  Address 0x443facb is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==20490==    at 0x402AF41: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==20490==    by 0x8048BDC: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:34)
==20490==    by 0x80487F6: main (main.cpp:60)
==20490== 
==20490== Invalid write of size 1
==20490==    at 0x8048C82: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:41)
==20490==    by 0x80487F6: main (main.cpp:60)
==20490==  Address 0x443facb is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==20490==    at 0x402AF41: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==20490==    by 0x8048BDC: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:34)
==20490==    by 0x80487F6: main (main.cpp:60)
==20490== 
==20490== Invalid write of size 1
==20490==    at 0x8048C76: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:38)
==20490==    by 0x8048806: main (main.cpp:61)
==20490==  Address 0x443fb42 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==20490==    at 0x402AF41: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==20490==    by 0x8048BDC: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:34)
==20490==    by 0x8048806: main (main.cpp:61)
==20490== 
==20490== Invalid write of size 1
==20490==    at 0x8048C82: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:41)
==20490==    by 0x8048806: main (main.cpp:61)
==20490==  Address 0x443fb42 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==20490==    at 0x402AF41: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==20490==    by 0x8048BDC: String::String(char const*) (main.cpp:34)
==20490==    by 0x8048806: main (main.cpp:61)
==20490== 
==20490== 
==20490== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20490==     in use at exit: 18,944 bytes in 1 blocks
==20490==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 6 frees, 18,997 bytes allocated
==20490== 
==20490== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20490==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20490==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20490==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20490==    still reachable: 18,944 bytes in 1 blocks
==20490==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20490== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20490== 
==20490== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20490== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

After fixing new[strlen] to new[strlen+1] ->

```
==21539== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==21539== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==21539== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==21539== Command: go
==21539== 
==21539== 
==21539== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21539==     in use at exit: 18,944 bytes in 1 blocks
==21539==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 6 frees, 19,000 bytes allocated
==21539== 
==21539== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21539==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21539==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21539==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21539==    still reachable: 18,944 bytes in 1 blocks
==21539==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21539== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==21539== 
==21539== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21539== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

But some remarks on your code:

```
String::~String() 
{
    m_string.reset();
}
```

Why??? If class is destructed the pointer will destructed which automatically results in freeing the pointer itself. It is stupid to do it twice! Leave the destructor empty, use the automatic one!

```
for (size_t i = 0; i <= m_len; i++) {
    *(m_string.get() + i*sizeof(char)) = obj[i];
    if (i == m_len)
    {
        *(m_string.get() + i*sizeof(char)) = '\0';
    }
}
```

Is the same as `strcpy`! If you use `strlen` to get the size, you can also use the copy from the libs.

```
String::String(const char* obj) : m_len(strlen(obj))
{
    shared_ptr<char> ptr(unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[m_len]));
    m_string = ptr;
```

Should be replaced with:

```
String::String(const char* obj) : m_len(strlen(obj)), m_string{ new char[m_len+1], delArray<char>() } { ... }
```

where delArray is:

```
template< typename T >
struct delArray { void operator ()( T const * p) { delete[] p; } };
```

There are some more unusual code fragments...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It worked now, even tho i tried that as a 6502 already pointed it out. Also thank you for the feedback on the code, much appreciated. Why should the unique_ptr be taken out and replaced?

Comment: Sorry, but I have not understand what your shared and unique pointer combination is good for. If your code own a single instance which must not be shared, use a unique pointer. If you share the resource, use a shared one. I have no idea if you give external access to the pointer to users of your object. So it depends :-) But you should simply use std::string and forget your code. It is only good for learning I believe. A string class should also be aware of `move` and so on. So please do not use your code in a real application!

Comment: I will definitely not use my code in real applications! It is for learning purposes only. :) thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
 new char[m_len]
```

allocates exactly `m_len` characters, but you're using `m_len+1` characters because of the ending NUL `\0` (you're actually writing to that unavailable location TWICE, once for looping with `<=` and once again explicitly for some strange reason).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the code to `shared_ptr<char> ptr(unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[m_len+1]));
 m_string = ptr;

 for (size_t i = 0; i <= m_len; i++) {
  
  if (i != m_len)
  {
   *(m_string.get() + i*sizeof(char)) = obj[i];
   
  }
  else {
   *(m_string.get() + i*sizeof(char)) = '\0';
  }
 }` but the error seems to persist.

Answer (score -1):

> class String

I found your mistake.

After swapping your string class for the Standard string class, I cannot reproduce the problem.